# Using Handler to sendMessage in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, message-queue

Dears. Im studying Android development and I'm stuck on Handlers/Loopers and MessageQueue.
According to documentation, Handlers are able to sendMessage and post(Runnable) to another thread, so I've tried the following:

I have two java files, one for a different class:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread(String argument) {
        //save the arguments to some member attribute
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //calculate something
        String result = doSomething();

        //now I need send this result to the MainActivity.
        //Ive tried this
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("someKey", result);
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = 2;
        msg.setData(bundle);

        //I hope this could access the Main Thread message queue
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

And my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        //super and inflate the layout
        //use findViewById to get some View
    }

    //I think this could access the same MessageQueue as the thread did
    private Handler mHandler = new Hander() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 2) {
                //I thought the sendMessage invoked inside the Thread
                //would go here, where I can process the bundle and
                //set some data to a View element and not only Thread change
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I could not understand how it really works reading the examples and documentation, I'd like a simple explanation in how can I get some data from a Thread (which does not know the MainActivity) to be displayed into a View inside Activity or Fragment.

Thanks

Comment: from where you started that MyThread

Comment: Currently from a button's onClick inside MainActivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think basically you created 2 handlers on the UI thread from your implementation. That is why in the MainActivity you didn't get called back.

You can try get a reference of the mHandler in the MyThread, and call sendMessage() on it. In this way, you are using single handler for your job.

Comment: You're right.I figured out that the Main Thread already have it's own implicit Handler.
Even if I create a new one (inside the Thread) passing the MainLooper, it's not the same Handler which is already bound to the MainThread.
To solve this, I had to pass the MainThread Handler to the MyThread and use it to send the messages.

Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In your example main is `Looper.getMainLooper()`, this means it will send the message to the `Handler` which is attached to the UI thread, In your case, `MainActivity` is running in UI thread and it has Handler in the name of `Handler` so the message will receive at `handleMessage` of that.

You can read more about [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html), [Communicating with the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html), [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)